# Why $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] is returning a CSS file?

Tags: php, css, referrer, referer

I need to capture the origin of the traffic to our websites, it works for the most part, but there are some sessions that have the HTTP_REFERER = https://www.mywebsite.com/css/style.css which is odd, once my CSS file is not the page that sent us the traffic.

Comment: Some `CSS` styles can contain URLs, like `background-image: url(...)`. If one of these styles refers to the PHP script, the referrer will be the CSS file.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the referer is set by a client and can contain anything. It's user-generated data, don't trust it.